# Cheap 1080 or expensive 1070?

Tags: graphics-cards

I am currently thinking about a new graphics card, for gaming, also for graphics. I am willing to spend around 500 bucks. I saw on alternate.de that some 1080s and 1070s are in a similar price range and I wanted to know what would be better, a cheaper 1080 model or a 1070 model in the same price range.
For example those two:

https://m.alternate.de/mobile/details.xhtml?p=1330180&page=1&t=8406
https://m.alternate.de/mobile/details.xhtml?p=1280375&page=1&t=8406

The 1080 has some higher stats, especially more streaming processors. So I would assume that the 1080 is better. But other 1080s, which cost more are just slightly better, stat wise, so there has to be a reason why this one is cheaper than the others. Both have good reviews. The 1080 seems to be are bit louder, but that's not important to me. Overclocking is also not a priority.

So what do you say would be better?

Comment: What are your requirements? I'd probably go for a cheaper 1070 without more detail. The GTX 1070 is good for all current games, usually above 60 FPS for 1080p/Ultra, playable at dual monitor or QHD and for the less demanding games, also at UHD/4K resolution. While the MSI card is good, it's not worth 140 Euros more than the cheaper [Zotac "Mini" variant](https://m.alternate.de/mobile/details.xhtml?p=1297479). You won't see a big performance difference, given that they are all the same chip, though there are differences in cooling and noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the 1080. I normally stick to the Power/Costs chart on https://www.computerbase.de/thema/grafikkarte/rangliste/ (for Germany) and normally it's a linear slope until a certain point, where you get less power for much more money, since they make their flagships more expensive for the high-end user.
But at the moment, probably because of crypto-mining, even the cheaper models are more expensive, so that it's more or less a linear behaviour over the full chart. So at the moment, sticking to the 1080 would be more beneficial. However, in future I would go back to that chart and buy the most powerful graphics card, which is still on the linear slope of that chart.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting article. So the reason why this particular 1080 is so cheap compared to other models is propably only inferior cooling rather than missing power, right?